# How to run as admin?

Tags: superuser

How to make this bat script run as admin either on the local computer as a scheduled task or startup up scrip?

forfiles -p "C:\ProgramData\ESET\ESET Endpoint Antivirus\Logs\eScan" -s -m *.dat /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: task scheduler lets you specify an account to use for the job...

Answer (score -1):

If you are just running this once, and not automating a number of scripts, you can just hold shift and right click to run as admin.